# Image build system that derives from a base Windows 8.1 image

Tags: windows, virtualization, installation, windows-8.1, vdi

For our VDI deployment, we have several Windows 8.1 images for target groups that require different suites of applications.

The current update procedure requires us to update the OS on each individual VDI image.

We would prefer to have one OS image and then build derivative images from that base with the required applications.

- What tools should we look into to accomplish this?
- Any strategies we should be aware of to address the inefficiency of the current procedure?

Comment: Please describe your current process. Do you clone a Win8.1 base image or are you loading Win8.1 by hand as well?

Comment: The initial images are cloned. However, after that, each update is done on all those individual clones.